# What distribution should I apply to estimate the likelihood of extreme returns?

Tags: risk, risk-management, probability, estimation, distribution

Say I have a limited sample, a month of daily returns, and I want to estimate the 99.5th percentile of the distribution of absolute daily returns.

Because the estimate will require extrapolation, I will need to make a distributional assumption. Is there a standard approach to take here if I want to include the higher kurtosis in my estimate?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you refer to as the 99.5th percentile is known as the "Value-at-Risk."  You are correct that you will need to make a distributional assumption, and there is a popular and well-researched approach to this problem, though I'm not certain it could be called "standard."  I would recommend you use the "truncated Levy flight" distribution.  James Xiong at Morningstar has written a few [papers](http://corporate.morningstar.com/ib/documents/MethodologyDocuments/IBBAssociates/UsingTruncatedLevyFlightToEstimateDownsideRisk.pdf) on this topic, and you can find more by googling him and this topic.  [Here](http://corporate.morningstar.com/ib/documents/MethodologyDocuments/IBBAssociates/NailingDownsideRisk.pdf) is a less technical, more introductory piece on the topic.

Also, you should consider other risk measures, most notably Expected Shortfall (ES), also known as Conditional-Value-at-Risk (CVaR), which examines not just what the 99.5% percentile is, but what the conditional expected return is beyond that point.  I also recommend you read this [MSCI piece](http://www.mscibarra.com/research/articles/2010/Extreme_Risk_Analysis_JPM_Spring_2010.pdf) on the topic.