# Inferring Returns From Minimal Data Points

Tags: time-series, risk, quant-trading-strategies, backtesting, expected-return

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How much data is needed to validate a short-horizon trading strategy?](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/1891/how-much-data-is-needed-to-validate-a-short-horizon-trading-strategy)

Suppose I have daily returns for a trading strategy against one month of data. Before starting trading on small quantities or buying further data, I would like to understand the worth of any such action. I am basically looking at the returns per day and the standard deviation between these returns.

- Is there a standard theory that tells me about the *minimum number of data points* based on these factors  i.e. daily returns, mean return and standard deviation? A minimum number of data points that gives me some sort of a confidence range to invest further for data.
- Is there a standard theory that lets me infer some results into the future based on a standard approach?

Comment: You can't infer the future based on past results; that's just one of the harsh realities of backtesting. As for how much data is needed for a reliable backtest, see [How much data is needed to validate a short-horizon trading strategy?](http://quant.stackexchange.com/q/1891/35)

Comment: @chrisaycock I agree. However, I guess I did not put my question clearly. I basically wanted to estimate the likelihood of extreme returns because of my sample data being limited. I found the following discussion on the topic: 
http://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/3839/what-distribution-should-i-apply-to-estimate-the-likelihood-of-extreme-returns

And thanks for the link, it answers my question. I guess that renders this post as "redundant" :)

Comment: @Aziz No problem, glad you found your answer.  Your post has been closed as a duplicate, but feel free to post new questions after you've looked around to see what we already have here.